# A problem determinant whose entries are from a equation involving kronecker delta

Tags: linear-algebra

A problem determinant whose entries are from a equation involving kronecker delta
Let $A_n$ be the $n × n$ matrix whose $(i, j )$-th entry is given by
$2δ_{ij} – δ_{i+1,j} – δ_{i,j +1}$
where $δ_{ij}$ equals $1$ if $i = j$  and zero otherwise. Compute the determinant of $A_n$

how can I solve this proble.try to do by taking few examples but get confused

Comment: See  Golub, Gene H.; Van Loan, Charles F. (1996). Matrix Computations (3rd ed. ed.) in http://books.google.com.br/books?id=mlOa7wPX6OYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Matrix+Computations&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=4dr2UM_EI4ao9gT5iYCgBg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Matrix%20Computations&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the matrix is [tridiagonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix) ($2$ on principal diagonal and $-1$ on sub and super-diagonals). You can now show that the determinant is given by a recurrence relation
$$
D_n = 2D_{n-1} - D_{n-2}
$$

with $D_1=2$ and $D_2=3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1) Present your matrix in explicit form:

$\left(
  \begin{array}{ccccc}
    2 & -1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
    -1 & 2 & ... & ... & ... \\
    0 & ... & ... & ... & 0 \\
    ... & ... & ... & ... & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & ... & -1 & 2 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$

2) Bring it to the triangular form and note that the diagonal elements are terms of the sequence $\{\frac{k+1}{k-1}\}_{k=1}^n$

3) Using property of triangular matrix ([The determinant of a triangular matrix equals the product of the diagonal entries.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix)) you can obtain the answer $\det(A_n)=n+1$.